# Centralizer of group: $c(a)=c(a^{-1})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I want to prove that $\forall \mathbb a \in  G$, $\mathbb c(a)=c(a^{-1}) $

> Is that true:
>   $$
> \begin{align*}
> x\in C(a)
> &\Leftrightarrow xa=ax\\
> &\Leftrightarrow a^{-1}xaa^{-1}=a^{-1}axa^{-1}\\
> &\Leftrightarrow a^{-1}xe=exa^{-1}\\
> &\Leftrightarrow a^{-1}x=xa^{-1}\\
> &\Leftrightarrow x\in C(a^{-1})
> \end{align*}
> $$

Comment: + You succeeded.

Comment: This is so simple that no question actually was needed.

Comment: Faisal Jamal: I have retyped your post based on the picture. If you are satisfied with the way it looks, you can remove the picture. (Of course, if needed, edit the post further.) For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).